# What are all the reasons `fgetc()` might return `EOF`?

Tags: c, fgetc

Certainly `fgetc()` returns `EOF` when *end-of-file* or an *input error* occurs.
Is that all and does that mean no more data is available?

```
FILE *inf = ...;
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(inf)) != EOF) {
  ;
}
if (feof(inf)) puts("End-of-file");
else if (ferror(inf)) puts("Error");
else puts("???");
```

Is testing with `feof(), ferror()` sufficient?

Note: `EOF` here is a macro that evaluates to some negative `int`, often `-1`.  It is **not** a synonym for *end-of-file*.

I have found [some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c+fgetc) [and more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bc%5D%20fgetc) that are close to this issue, yet none that enumerate all possibilities.

Comment: I do look forward other answers (not just my own in this "answer my own question").

Comment: Also, my interpretation is that `feof()` is the complement of `ferror()` when reading eof, but this may be a flawed assumption.

Comment: @Neil [John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53274876/2410359) answer to a related question may be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is that all and does that mean no more data available?

No, there are more ways for `EOF`. 
An `EOF` does not certainly mean no more data - it depends.

The C library lists three cases where `fgetc()` returns `EOF`.

> If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, or if the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set and the `fgetc` function returns `EOF`. Otherwise, the `fgetc` function returns the next character from the input stream pointed to by stream. If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and the `fgetc` function returns `EOF`.  C17dr § 7.21.7.1 3

Recall each *stream*, like `stdin`, has an *end-of-file indicator* and *error indicator*.

- **stream just encountered the end-of-file**

  (Most common) An attempt has been made to get more data, but there was none.
- **end-of-file indicator for the stream is set**

  The stream first examines its *end-of-file indicator*.  If it sees that the indicator is set, it returns `EOF`.  No attempt is made to see if more data exists.  Some types of streams will report `EOF`, but data will have arrived after the prior `EOF` report.  Until the *end-of-file indicator* is cleared as with `clearerr()`, the return remains `EOF`. [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56755955/2410359). [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57272367/2410359).
- **Input error**

  The stream *error* indicator is **not** examined.  Yet the function failed for some reason to read data other than end-of-file.  A common example is `fputc(stdin)`.  Often input errors are persistent.  Some are not.  More data may be available.  The common strategy is to end the input.

  ```
    // Example where ferror() is true, yet fgetc() does not return EOF
    FILE *inf = stdin;
    printf("end-of-file:%d error:%d\n", feof(inf), ferror(inf));
    printf("fputc():%d\n", fputc('?', inf));  // EOF reported
    printf("end-of-file:%d error:%d\n", feof(inf), ferror(inf));
    printf("fgetc():%d\n", fgetc(inf));  // User typed in `A`, 'A' reported
    printf("end-of-file:%d error:%d\n", feof(inf), ferror(inf));
  ```

  Output

  ```
  end-of-file:0 error:0
  fputc():-1
  end-of-file:0 error:1
  fgetc():65
  end-of-file:0 error:1
  ```

  When `ferror()` is true, it does not mean the error just occurred, just sometime in the past.

**Other cases**

- **Apparent `EOF` due to improperly saving as `char`**

  `fgetc()` returns an `int` with a value in the `unsigned char` range and `EOF` - a negative value. 
  When `fgetc()` reads character code 255, yet saves that as a `char` on a system where `char` is *signed*, that commonly results in the `char` having the same value as `EOF`, yet end-of-file did not occur.

  ```
      FILE *f = fopen("t", "w");
      fputc(EOF & 255, f);
      fclose(f);
      f = fopen("t", "r");
      char ch = fgetc(f); // Should be int ch
      printf ("%d %d\n", ch == EOF, ch);
      printf("end-of-file:%d error:%d\n", feof(f), ferror(f));
      fclose(f);
  ```

  Output

  ```
  1 -1  // ch == EOF !
  end-of-file:0 error:0
  ```
- **Systems where `UCHAR_MAX == UINT_MAX`**. *Rare*.

  (I have only come across this in some older graphics processors, still something C allows.)  In that case, `fgetc()` may read an `unsigned char` outside the `int` range and so convert it to `EOF` on the function return.  Thus `fgetc()` is returning a character code that happens to equal `EOF`.  This is mostly an oddity in the C history. A way to mostly handle is:

  ```
    while ((ch = fgetc(inf)) != EOF && !feof(inf) && !ferror(inf)) {
      ;
    }
  ```

  Such pedantic code is rarely needed.
- ***Undefined behavior***

  Of course when [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) occurs, anything is possible.

  ```
        FILE * f = fopen("Some_non_existent_file", "r");
        // Should have tested f == NULL here
        printf("%d\n", fgetc(f) == EOF); // Result may be 1
  ```

---

A robust way to handle the return from `fgetc()`.

```
FILE *inf = ...;
if (inf) {  // Add test
  int ch; // USE int !

  // Pedantic considerations, usually can be ignored
  #if UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX
    clearerr(inf); // Clear history of prior flags
    while ((ch = fgetc(inf)) != EOF && !feof(inf) && !ferror(inf)) {
      ;
    }
  #else
    while ((ch = fgetc(inf)) != EOF) {
      ;
    }
  #endif

  if (feof(inf)) puts("End-of-file");
  else puts("Error");
```

If code needs to look for data after *end-of-file* or *error*, call `clearerr()` and repeat the `if()` block.

Comment: Note: `[f]printf()` might reset `errno`.

Comment: @wildplasser True that "The value of errno may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of `errno` is not documented in the description of the function ....", but how does that affect things here? `errno` is not the file _error indicator_.

Comment: I suggest adding this (my favorite): reading byte 0x1a on Windows in text mode sets the EOF flag.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Useful to add that "reading byte 0x1a on Windows in text mode sets the EOF flag" an an answer, but I suspect that is a compiler issue, not an OS one.

Comment: I think it's the case on both MinGW and MSVC, so 'on windows' was a shorthand. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat With gcc on windows, the favorite is not there.  Perhaps I misunderstand your thoughts?

Comment: Hmm, it works at least in Wine. I think it should work on actual Windows too, but I won't be able to test until monday.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Any testing results?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I completely forgot. :| Tested it on both MSYS2 GCC (MINGW64 environment) and MSVC, on Win 10. Was able to reproduce on both.

Answer (score 5):

Another case where EOF doesn't necessarily mean 'no more data' was (rather than 'is') reading magnetic tapes.  You could have multiple files on a single tape, with the end of each marked with EOF.  When you encountered EOF, you used `clearerr(fp)` to reset the EOF and error states on the file stream, and you could then continue reading the next file on the tape.  However, magnetic tapes have (for the most part) gone the way of the dodo, so this barely counts any more.

Comment: This happens on a terminal too -- if you indicate an EOF (by hitting a system-specific key combo, usually ctrl-D or ctrl-Z) a program reading from the terminal will get an EOF.  If that program then uses clearerr, it can read more from the terminal.

Comment: @ChrisDodd — that depends on which platform you're on, and/or which version of glibc you are using.  You're right that on some (probably many) Linux systems, typing the EOF indicator (usually control-D) does not permanently set the EOF indicator.  On most other Unix systems, once you indicate EOF on the terminal, you continue to get EOF until you clear the error and EOF indicator with `clearerr()`.  RHEL 7.4 suffers from what I regard as 'this bug'; macOS (all versions I've used), does not.

Comment: right, but if you do call `clearerr`, you can then continue to read from the terminal

Comment: If you try this code: `#include <stdio.h> int main(void) { for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) putchar(c); puts("EOF received"); } return 0; }` on your systems, you'll find that many (most) non-Linux systems take the first EOF and it remains in effect (so you get three lines saying "`EOF received`" immediately), but many Linux systems accept multiple lots of input with the EOF indicator typed between different sets of input.

Comment: Yes, if you call `clearerr()`, you can continue reading from the terminal on all systems that I know of.

Comment: Magnetic tapes are very much still used in commercial settings when there's a need to archive a huge amount of data and not access it frequently: tape wins over hard disk in terms of price per GB of the storage media alone. That said, you would probably be using some vendor-provided software to access the tape these days, rather than accessing the device directly from C, so you probably wouldn't run into this issue there anymore. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_Tape-Open

Answer (score 2):

Here's one obscure reason:

**On Windows, reading byte `0x1A` in text mode causes EOF.**

By "Windows" I mean both MSVC and MinGW (so it's probably a quirk of Microsoft's CRT). This doesn't happen on Cygwin.